# How to put router in function and export it?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to put router.post in a function and export it to app.js. But it didn't take effect. Here is my code.

---

crypto.js

```js
function getPublicKey() {
    console.log('111');
    router.post('/get-public-key', (req, res) => {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/keys/rsa-pub.pem', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            } else {
                res.send(data)
            }
        })
    });
}


module.exports = {
getPublicKey
}
```

---

app.js

```js
const cryptoRouter = require('./modules/crypto/router');
cryptoRouter.getPublicKey();
```

---

It printed '111'.But I cannot POST /get-public-key.
How should I do?Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to require, then you must export the function, like `module.exports = getPublicKey`.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Sorry.I have wrote this code.But just forgot writing.

Comment: But it is wrong. Try without the brackets, just like I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Thanks for your help.I used your code.But it still print '111' and the router didn't work

Comment: You can't post because this `router` in your code is coming from nowhere. It is not the same router in the rest of your code. Have in mind that the same word may represent entirely different things in different modules.  Aren't you receiving some warning about this in your console?

Comment: No,nothing warning in console,only '111'.I used to export router and use 'app.use('/crypto',cryptoRouter.router)' in app.js.It works well.Today I want to put router in a function and export this function for deciding whether to use this router in the future. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getPublicKey` should return the public key instead

```
function getPublicKey() {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/keys/rsa-pub.pem', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        return data
    })
}
```

Then, in `app.js`

```
app.post('/get-public-key', (req, res) => {
    res.send(getPublicKey)
})
```

### Edit

If you wanna use `router`, you should do like this:

```
// ./routes/somewhere.js
const router = require('express').Router()

router.post('/something', (req, res) => {
    res.send('You made it!')
})

module.exports = router
```

Then

```
// ./app.js
app.use('/somewhere', require('./routes/somewhere'))
```

Finally, you can make a post request to `/somewhere/something`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I export router and registered router in app.js.It works well.But I want to control the router and decide whether use it.So I put the router in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance of `app` to your function and return the route

```
function getPublicKey(app) {
  console.log('111');
  return app.post('/get-public-key', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/keys/rsa-pub.pem', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      } else {
        res.send(data)
      }
    })
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getPublicKey
}
```

Then in your `app.js` you could simply invoke by passing in the instance of `app`:

```
const cryptoRouter = require('./modules/crypto/router');
cryptoRouter.getPublicKey(app);
```

Comment: It says"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."I will mark accepted after.